# TypeORM/NestJS "type "geography" does not exist" when running tests

Tags: testing, nestjs, typeorm, postgis, nestjs-typeorm

Created a new entity column on a table that looks like this:

```
@Column({
    type: 'geography',
    spatialFeatureType: 'Point',
    srid: 4326,
    nullable: true,
  })
  geography: Point
```

I am configuring the test module using NestJS and TypeORM. Based on the source code [here](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/92b96a550512bb218e1c6691e2f5908007d0b6e6/src/driver/postgres/PostgresDriver.ts#L397) and [here](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/92b96a550512bb218e1c6691e2f5908007d0b6e6/src/driver/postgres/PostgresDriver.ts#L359), it seems as though by default, TypeORM installs Postgis if a `geography` column is detected, but I keep getting this error: `QueryFailedError: type "geography" does not exist`.

Here is the configuration I have for the test module:

```
export const testingModule = (providers: Provider[]) => {
  return Test.createTestingModule({
    imports: [
      TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
        useFactory: () =>  {
      type: 'postgres',
      url: getEnv('DATABASE_URL'),
      dropSchema: true,
      autoLoadEntities: true,
      synchronize: true,
      logging: false,
      namingStrategy: new SnakeNamingStrategy(),
      keepConnectionAlive: false,
    },
        dataSourceFactory: async (options: any) => ... // returns datasource
        },
      }),
      TypeOrmModule.forFeature(
        Location,
      ),
      EventEmitterModule.forRoot(),
    ],
    providers,
  })
}
```

Am I missing something here?

I also tried using the dataSourceFactory to explicitly add Postgis using the data source, but I believe this isn't happening synchronously, so I think the line to install Postgis happens after the schema is created  (which contains the geography column, hence the error).

This works as designed in our regular environments, but unable to get this to play nice with the testing module from NestJS.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I went about it.
I first added `manualInitialization` to my data source config and set it to `true.` This prevents `TypeOrmModule` from automatically initializing the database.

```
 TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
          useFactory: () => {
            //N.B: I use process.env here instead of configService.get
            // because of e2e tests. process.env can be mutated and updated
            // with connection details for a testcontainer database
    
            return {
              type: 'postgres' as const,
              host: process.env.DB_HOST,
              port: parseInt(process.env.DB_PORT),
              username: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
              password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
              database: process.env.DB_NAME,
              autoLoadEntities: true,
              synchronize: IS_DEV,
              logging: false,
              manualInitialization: true, <------ HERE
            };
          },
        })
```

I did that because I wanted to initialize the database manually to prevent this:

> I think the line to install Postgis happens after the schema is created (which contains the geography column, hence the error).

In my test file, in the `beforeAll` hook, I create the `postgis` extension before manually initializing the database as shown below:

```
 beforeAll(async () => {
    ........
    
         app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
  

     const datasourceService = app.get(DataSourceService);
        const datasource = datasourceService.getDatasource();
            try {
               await datasource.initialize();
     HERE ----> await datasource.query(`CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "postgis"`);
            } catch (error) {
              console.error(error);
            }
            await app.init();
    
    ......
    });
```

I ran into the error: `QueryFailedError: extension "postgis" is not available`. `The extension must first be installed on the system where PostgreSQL is running`.

So I ran `brew install postgis` (I'm on a Mac. It installed a ton of packages.), and then I reran the test.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried adding `manualnitialization` but am still struggling to get this to work as we don't want to be installing postgis on each test file manually. Going to open an issue on github as this looks like it should be out of the box functionality.